# ArcPy to perform "select by attribute" and display the result on the map in a table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, display

I am thinking to use ArcPy to select by attribute, after that I want to display the selected features attribute in a table on the map, how can I make it?

Answer (score 2):

Make your table look like you want it to in your layout; change field aliases, hide fields you don't want etc. When you're done, use the "Add table to layout" button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin,
But the fact is I create a new tool (in arctoolbox), this tool allow user to search from the map, the tool need to call the python script to realize the searching purpose. Thus what I need to do is to display the selected feature in a table on map(through the python script).